# React - Optimize preview for large amount of photos

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I am currently working on a React project where users can upload a substantial number of photos (around 400+) using the react-dropzone library. While the file upload functionality is working as expected, I am facing performance issues when it comes to generating and displaying photo previews.

Photos are loading slow and scroll lag is very strong with 400+ photos (5-6MB per photo is average). Photos are in jpg format.

In my onDrop handler, I have the following logic:

```
// ...imports
import {useDropzone} from "react-dropzone"

export const ImageDrop: React.FC<ImageDropProps> = ({}) => {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState<File[]>([])

  const onDrop = useCallback(
    (acceptedFiles: File[]) => {
      if (acceptedFiles?.length) {
        setFiles((prevFiles) => {
          const newFiles = [];
          for (const file of acceptedFiles) {
            if (file.type === 'image/jpeg') {
              Object.assign(file, { preview: URL.createObjectURL(file) });
              newFiles.push(file);
            }
          }
  
          return [...prevFiles, ...newFiles];
        });
      }
    },
    [disabled, maxPhotoSize, maxPhotos, setFiles, t],
  );
  
  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({
    onDrop,
    disabled,
  });
  
  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <div {...getRootProps()}>
          {!disabled && <input {...getInputProps()} />}
        </div>
      </form>
      {files.map((file, index) => (
        <div
          className='relative h-32 w-32 cursor-zoom-in select-none items-center justify-center'
          key={file.name}
        >
          <div
            className='absolute inset-0 -left-2 -top-2 z-20 h-8 w-8 cursor-pointer rounded-full border-2 border-foreground bg-content1 opacity-75 transition-all duration-300 hover:scale-125 hover:opacity-100'
            onClick={() => onRemove(file.name)}
          >
            <TrashIcon className='mx-auto pt-1 text-foreground' />
          </div>{' '}
          <img
            src={file.preview}
            className='max-w-36 max-h-36 rounded-lg bg-content2 p-1'
            style={{
              objectFit: 'cover',
              objectPosition: 'center',
              aspectRatio: '1/1',
            }}
            alt={file.name}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

I have tried [this solution](https://gist.github.com/imanubhardwaj/a6791c3f543ea205ea34d66679983ee5) but when I drop many photos, it takes too long for them to show (no lag after tho).

The goal is to find a way to optimize the photo preview generation process, ensuring a smooth user experience even when dealing with a large number of photos. I want to avoid any lag or delays in the application due to the photo preview generation.

I'm open to suggestions. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not familiar with `react-dropzone` but I would guess the lag originates at the end of your `onDrop` callback where you copy all the files in your `setFiles` state call (`return [...prevFiles, ...newFiles]`). Do you need to store the raw file data inside that array or could you just store an array of object URLs generated by `URL#createObjectURL`?

Comment: I'd use a combination of pagination (only fetch a certain size at a time) and lazy-loaded `<img>` tags so the browser only attempts to render images that are within the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Image resize: consider using [pica](https://github.com/nodeca/pica).
Optimizing preview generation: by your code, you make a preview for all images and only then render it. I assume you don`t show 400+ photos at once, so you can add setFiles([...prevFiles, ...newFiles]) for 10 or more, render them and continue resizing others